# How to copycloning a Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, clone

I wish to clone(programmatic) a Canvas element in WPF, to avoid adding new/same element in project elements (Document Outline).
For example I have a collection of Path's in my canvas Element/Control - and this element takes approximately 300Kb of project size. If I add more and more the same element, the exe file come enormous.

I find in other pages info about that question, and answer/solution - for that comes in that line of code :

```
class WpfObjectCopier
    {
        public static T Clone<T>(T source)
        {
            var objXaml = XamlWriter.Save(source);
            var stringReader = new StringReader(objXaml);
            var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            var t = (T)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            return t;
        }
    }
```

Usage :

```
object obj = WpfObjectCopier.Clone(Delimiter);
```

And problem is/comes from choosing different .Margin or another condition.
How I can solve that kind of problem?

Comment: Why do you need to add same same XAML all over again? Can you not create `UserĆontrol` and if you need to repeat it use some `ItemsControl` with `DataTemplate`?

Comment: I agree with @dkozl, it looks like you're asking for help with a bad solution. Take a step back and ask about what you really want.

Comment: Okey, I have a Canvas element drawed in Illustrator, I use it to delimit a center screen in my application. Looks like this : http://i.imgur.com/PuuKKTN.png - you will see a white element in the middle - that is the element to clone, without creating the same elements. Is that okey ?

Comment: And what do you want to do with this 'clone'?

Comment: complete the line of center screen like this : http://i.imgur.com/iXYrEF4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *visually* clone a UI element in WPF is easy using the [`VisualBrush` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They all extend the `Visual` class which is useful, because an instance of the `Visual` class is required by the [`VisualBrush.Visual` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.visual%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This means that any UI element can be used *as a `Brush`* to paint any other UI element. Here's a simple example from which I'm sure you can find your answer:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="VisualBrush" 
            Visual="{Binding ., ElementName=ComplicatedPath}" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Path Name="ComplicatedPath" Width="75" Height="15" Data="Oh my gosh!" />
    <Rectangle Width="75" Height="15" Fill="{StaticResource VisualBrush}" 
        StrokeThickness="0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That's great!! Thank You, if you know ho to do the same in code(programmatically)?

Comment: Dude, we *don't* programmatically declare UI elements in WPF... get used to the XAML... that is how it is done.